# Fahrenheit to Celisus choice option

Tags: c

The way my program is written it will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and then Fahrenheit to Celsius using functions. What I would like it to do is give you the option to choose. This was a homework assignment from a couple of weeks ago, and I obviously didn't get it right. I would like to know how it should have been written if anyone would like to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Function Declarations

float get_Celsius (float* Celsius);       
void to_Fahrenheit (float cel);           
float get_Fahrenheit (float* Fahrenheit);
void to_Celsius (float fah);             


int main (void)
{
   //Local Declarations
   float Fahrenheit;
   float Celsius;
   int opt

   //Statements
   printf("Please enter a temperature value in Celsius to be converted to Fahrenheit:\n");
   a = get_Celsius(&Celsius);
   to_Fahrenheit(a);
   printf("Please enter a temperature value in Fahrenheit to be converted to  Celsius:\n");
   b = get_Fahrenheit(&Fahrenheit);
   to_Celsius(b);

   return 0;
} //main

 float get_Celsius (float* Celsius)
{
   //Statements
   scanf("%f", &*Celsius);
   return *Celsius;
}

void to_Fahrenheit (float cel)
{
   //Local Declarations
   float fah;

   //Statements
   fah = ((cel*9)/5) + 32;
   printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit is: %f\n", fah);
   return;
}

float get_Fahrenheit (float* Fahrenheit)
{
   //Statements
   scanf("%f", &*Fahrenheit);
   return *Fahrenheit;
}

void to_Celsius (float fah)
{
   //Local Declarations
   float cel;

   //Statements
   cel = (fah-32) * (5.0/9.0);
   printf("The temperature in Celsius is: %f\n", cel);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Change *obviously didn't get it right* to exactly how it doesn't work and expected result.

Comment: Use `switch` for case.

Comment: I was trying to write a program that would give the user the option to choose between Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion or Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion. The program must give the user the option to choose and use functions and call the function to perform the operation. What I did not get right was program giving the user the option to choose.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to declare `a` and `b`, because the weren't declared.

Second, you missed the `;` from the declaration of opt.

Then you could ask for a number (1 or 2) with `scanf("%d", &opt);` and with the value of `opt` you could discriminate the instructions to execute with a couple of ifs, like this.

```
int main (void)
{
   //Local Declarations
   float a, b;
   float Fahrenheit;
   float Celsius;
   int opt;

   printf("Hi\n");
   printf("1) Convert from Celsius to Farenheit\n");
   printf("2) Convert from Farenheit to Celsius\n\n");
   printf("What Would you like to do?: ");
   scanf("%d", &opt);

   if (opt == 1) {
   //Statements
       printf("Please enter a temperature value in Celsius to be converted to Fahrenheit:\n");
       a = get_Celsius(&Celsius);
       to_Fahrenheit(a);
   }
   else if (opt == 2) {
       printf("Please enter a temperature value in Fahrenheit to be converted to  Celsius:\n");
       b = get_Fahrenheit(&Fahrenheit);
       to_Celsius(b);
   }
   else
        printf("Wrong option");

   return 0;
} //main
```

Comment: If you are using `if`, it would be better if you use `if-else-if` because it will help you to control poor option choice from user; otherwise use `switch` because of it's `default` case.

Comment: Thank you for answering my post. The opt was from one of my attempts to add the option of a choice. I don't know what I am doing wrong because even with your change I am still having issues. I don't think I am cut out for code. If you were to give me the entire program, I don't think I could make it work :(

Comment: @DonCarter What issues are you having? We cannot help if you don't specify your "issues". I would suggest you to read book on c because clearly you lack understanding the basics.

Comment: I think my main problem is in the function prototypes. I used pointers in the original program with the help of a friend but now they are an issue. With the addition of the option to choose which conversion, they are giving me errors.

Comment: Totoro, I know I do not have the basics down yet. I was taking a class on C and this was one of the assignments. I spent several hours trying to resolve my issues with this program. Between working full time, raising two children, and going to online college full time, it is hard to find time to fully absorb all of the material in five weeks. This class is over now and I simply wanted to see how my program should have looked. I didn't ask anyone to do my work for me, as other have, but I did try very hard to do it myself. Please don't judge me to harshly.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded to this post. I finally resolved the issues with my program. I had a couple of missing pointers and a couple of variables that weren't initialized.